# Change inserted value with trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I've just started to learn SQL a few weeks ago and I'm trying to make a trigger which changes the inserted value into 10 if it's smaller than 10. I searched for 4h now and I've found a lot of answers but none was good(for me). I really don't understand where the problem is.
Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NumberOfBooks
BEFORE INSERT
ON Book
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF new.nobook < 10
  THEN
    SET new.nobook = 10;
  END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error(8,9): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option and the set new.nobook = 10 is underlined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oracle's trigger syntax the newly inserted record is referred to by `:new`, not `new` (notice the colon). Additionally, `SET` is a part of an update statement, not a way to set field values - those are done by simple assignments, but note that these are done with `:=` rather than `=`.

So, your trigger should read:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NumberOfBooks
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON book
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.nobook < 10
    THEN
        :new.nobook := 10;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: thank you very much! I've edited the code and everything goes smoothly. Lifesaver.

Comment: I needed to use `:=`